# LinearLayout 2 views, if one is gone, it doesn't center the other, although I update the weightSum

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight, layout-gravity

this is my layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/car_linear_layout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/car_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/car_layout_name"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/car_layout_license"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is my code:

```
    if (userVehicleID != null) {
        carLayout.setWeightSum(2);
        carLicense.setText("test");
    }else{
        carLayout.setWeightSum(1);
        carLicense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

But even so, if I debug, and it enters the ELSE , it will show just the first textview, but it's not centered. why?

Comment: centered ? vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just remove `android:weightSum` from parent layout .

So if you set visibility of any child to `GONE` then the other child will cover the weight.If In your case parent layout is `wrap_content` after making a child as `GONE`,  this will make the Your parent `LinearLayout` height equal to Height of `VISIBLE` TextView. This is the way `layout_weight` works.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/car_linear_layout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/car_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
   >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/car_layout_name"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/car_layout_license"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to trigger a layout update (requestLayout())  to make the layout to recalculate it's children after changing the weightSum and hiding the view

Answer (score 2):

Do not change the `weightSum` or specify `textAlignment`.
Since you are setting `weightSum` to 2 it takes all available height and sets text only on top of view.

Comment: I made an update, after modifing weightSum and worked, thanks

Comment: if this helped you consider marking this as the answer so it can help the other. Thanks!